# Plot same plot again (or choose which plot to draw)

Tags: r, plot

I have a complex layout of plots, say for example

```
layout(matrix(1:2,nrow=1), widths=c(1,7))
```

I have drawn earlier plots, and am now working on a particular plot (e.g. working on the code on the plot). I redraw the plot often to see impacts of changing e.g. margins.

How can I avoid that each time I redraw the plot it moves on to the next plot in the layout?

e.g. each time I have to start from the beginning, call dev.off, call layout, plot the earlier plots, and then start again with my plot.

Can I just select which plot in the layout I want to plot? Can I move the "counter" that selects which plot is being plotted next?

Comment: If you need this, you should probably use `split.screen` instead of `layout`. Or switch to grid graphics.

Comment: FWIW, you could hack , using `layout`, by plotting a single point that's outside the x,y limits on each of the other plots in your page.  Simple enough to write a helper function to do this for all but the plot of interest.